# Showing and hiding a div on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, hide, show

Im need some help with working out some jQuery code...

I want to have a fixed side panel and within that panel I want to have a div element that shows and hides depending on where the user scrolls.

Example: So the user is at the top of the page and the left bar will say "intro". Then when they scroll down say 1000px "intro" fades out and "Section 1" fades in. Then when they scroll down another 1000px "Section 1" fades out and "Section 2" fades in. Then the reverse will happen when scrolling back up the page.

Im only just learning jQuery so I'm not overly good at working out the correct code/language. Ive currently got the "intro" fading out and the first section fading in but i can't work out how to do the rest...

Im assuming I need something like > 1000 && < 2000 for telling it when to show and hide but I'm not sure how to correctly write it.

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {

  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 950) {
    $('#intro').fadeIn("slow");
  } else {
    $('#intro').hide();
  }

  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1000) {
    $('#one').fadeIn("slow");
  } else {
    $('#one').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #D1A2A3;
}

.block2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #866061;
}

.sideBar {
  width: 300px;
  height:  100vh;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #5D5D5D;
}

#one {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sideBar">

  <div id="intro">
    <p>INTRO</p>
  </div>

  <div id="one">
    <p>ONE</p>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is and Example :)

```
<html><head>
<style>
div.block.active { opacity: 1 }
.block {opacity:0; background:black; width:150px; height:150px}
</style>
<script src=jquery.js></script>
</head><body style="height:2500px">
<div id=block1 class=block></div>
<div id=block2 class=block></div>
<!-- <div id=blockN class=block></div> -->

<script>
var blocks = {
  // your blocks
  1: {
    min: 100, // first block min height
    max: 200 // first block max height
  },
  2: {
    min: 200, // second block min height
    max: 300 // second block max height 
  }
  // And so on
  /*
  N: {
   min: height,
   max: height
   }
   */

}
var blocks_c = 0;
var j;
for (j in blocks) {
  if (blocks.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
    blocks_c++;
  }
}
$(window).scroll(function () {
  for (var i = 1; i <= blocks_c; i++) {
    var t = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (t > blocks[i].min && t < blocks[i].max) {
      $('div.block').removeClass('active');
      $('div#block' + i).addClass('active');
    }
  }
});

</script>
</body></html>
```